# Changing SSL-version for curl

Tags: ssl, openssl, curl, nss

I have been trying for hours to change the SSL Version for curl from NSS to OpenSSL because I have a web application that's dependant on it.

I'm running RedHat RHEL 6.7 on a 64-bit system.

I have read threads that say that I should set this when running ./configure but I have tried it with no success.

Really thankful for help!

Comment: What exactly did you try and how it failed?

Comment: I tried to setup a similar environment but on CentOS 6.7 and then I downloaded the latest version of curl (7.47.1) and ran ./configure --with-ssl=/usr/include --without-nss, make and make install. Then I rebooted but I couldn't see OpenSSL in curl -V

Comment: Let's start from the very beginning. What is the problem with curl and why do you need to build a custom one, instead of the one provided from an RHEL repo ?

Comment: The problem is that I am using a WordPress-plugin that establishes connections using a certificate in a plugin-folder. It's not working properly so the plugin-creator asked me if I ran NSS or OpenSSL for curl. When he realized that I were using NSS he said that for it to work with NSS I needed to put the certificate in a root-folder and link it and recommended me to switch to OpenSSL instead. I have searched the web wondering how to change from NSS to OpenSSL with no luck.

Comment: What if you run `/usr/local/bin/curl -V`?

Comment: `[~]# curl -V`
curl 7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.18 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
Protocols: tftp ftp telnet dict ldap ldaps http file https ftps scp sftp 
Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz

Comment: That is not what @rvs asked for!

Comment: `[~]# /usr/local/bin/curl -V`
-bash: /usr/local/bin/curl: No such file or directory

Comment: Okey I managed to recompile PHP with OpenSSL for curl instead of NSS using EasyApache 3 in WHM.